# реализация мобильного меню

Tags: javascript, события

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно адекватно реализовать мобильное меню на чистом `js`. проблема в том, что в моем контексте желательно обойтись без использования `stopPropagation`. был вариант повесить обработчик на `document` и отслеживать `target` и сделать условия при попадании на кнопку меню, но так при любом клике в холостую будет работать событие.

P.S: В моем примере проблема заключается в том, что когда меню открыто и клик происходит в области меню, срабатывают два события одновременно. Необходимо, что бы при клике в любую область страницы меня скрывалось.

```js
function menu() {
 let htmlNode = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],
   bodyNode = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
   menuNode = document.getElementsByClassName("header__menu")[0];

 function docListner(e) {
  htmlNode.classList.remove("html_fixed");
  bodyNode.classList.remove("page_translucent");
  menuNode.classList.remove("header__menu_open");
  document.removeEventListener("click", docListner);
  menuNode.addEventListener("click", menuListner);
 }

 function menuListner(e) {
  htmlNode.classList.add("html_fixed");
  bodyNode.classList.add("page_translucent");
  menuNode.classList.add("header__menu_open");
  menuNode.removeEventListener("click", menuListner);
  document.addEventListener("click", docListner, true);
 }

 menuNode.addEventListener("click", menuListner);
}

menu();
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body, p, figure, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
     margin: 0;
}
 ul, ol, dl, li, menu {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
}
 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
     display: none;
}
 button {
     outline: none;
     border: none;
     padding: 0;
}
 input, select {
     outline: none;
     border: none;
}
 a {
     text-decoration: none;
}
 i {
     font-style: normal;
}
 img {
     max-width: 100%;
     vertical-align: middle;
     border: none;
}
 .html_fixed {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
}
 .page {
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: background .5s ease-out 0s;
}
 .page_translucent {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
 .header {
     background: #512;
     display: flex;
     padding: 10px;
}
 .header__menu {
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     margin-left: auto;
     left: 0;
     transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
 .header__menu_open {
     left: -300px;
}
 .menu__button {
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: transparent;
}
 .menu__toggle {
     display: block;
     height: 8px;
     width: 50px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     background: #51a289;
}
 .menu__toggle:not(:last-child) {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .menu__content {
     position: absolute;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
     transform: translateX(100%);
     right: -10px;
     top: -10px;
     background: #cc9629;
     padding: 15px;
     width: 300px;
     height: 100vh;
}
 .menu__item {
     font-size: 18px;
}
 .menu__item:not(:last-child) {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .box {
     display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>html-ready</title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/favicon.png"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="page">
 <header class="header">
  <div class="menu header__menu">
   <button class="menu__button">
    <span class="menu__toggle"></span>
    <span class="menu__toggle"></span>
    <span class="menu__toggle"></span>
   </button>
   <menu class="menu__content">
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem.</li>
   </menu>
  </div>
 </header>
 <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: чем не устраивает `stopPropagation`?

Comment: @Grundy, зачастую прекращение всплытия создаёт свои подводные камни, которые потом приходится обходить. хотел спросить у тертых калачей как поступить лучше.

Comment: _прекращение всплытия создаёт свои подводные камни_ - какие?

Comment: @Grundy, [тык](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F). пролистай чуть ниже, и там будет пример.

Comment: Как пример в учебнике влияет на конкретно твой случай? _реализации чего-нибудь «эдакого»_ - говорит само за себя

Comment: @Grundy, для того что бы узнать твое мнение в частности я и задал вопрос)

Answer (score -1):

Держите... Один обработчик и всё готово. Не надо велосипеды изобретать.

```js
var  htmlNode = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],
   bodyNode = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
   menuNode = document.getElementsByClassName("header__menu")[0];
   menu = {};

menu.open = function(e){
  htmlNode.classList.add("html_fixed");
  bodyNode.classList.add("page_translucent");
  menuNode.classList.add("header__menu_open")
}

menu.close = function(){
  htmlNode.classList.remove("html_fixed");
  bodyNode.classList.remove("page_translucent");
  menuNode.classList.remove("header__menu_open");
}

document.addEventListener('click',function(e){

 // open menu
 if ((e.target.className == 'menu__button' || e.target.className == 'menu__toggle') && menuNode.className != 'menu header__menu header__menu_open')  {
  menu.open(e);  
 } 
 // close menu
 else {
  menu.close(e)
 }
})
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body, p, figure, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
     margin: 0;
}
 ul, ol, dl, li, menu {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
}
 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
     display: none;
}
 button {
     outline: none;
     border: none;
     padding: 0;
}
 input, select {
     outline: none;
     border: none;
}
 a {
     text-decoration: none;
}
 i {
     font-style: normal;
}
 img {
     max-width: 100%;
     vertical-align: middle;
     border: none;
}
 .html_fixed {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
}
 .page {
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: background .5s ease-out 0s;
}
 .page_translucent {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
 .header {
     background: #512;
     display: flex;
     padding: 10px;
}
 .header__menu {
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     margin-left: auto;
     left: 0;
     transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
 .header__menu_open {
     left: -300px;
}
 .menu__button {
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: transparent;
}
 .menu__toggle {
     display: block;
     height: 8px;
     width: 50px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     background: #51a289;
}
 .menu__toggle:not(:last-child) {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .menu__content {
     position: absolute;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
     transform: translateX(100%);
     right: -10px;
     top: -10px;
     background: #cc9629;
     padding: 15px;
     width: 300px;
     height: 100vh;
}
 .menu__item {
     font-size: 18px;
}
 .menu__item:not(:last-child) {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .box {
     display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>html-ready</title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/favicon.png"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="page">
 <header class="header">
  <div class="menu header__menu">
   <button class="menu__button">
    <span class="menu__toggle"></span>
    <span class="menu__toggle"></span>
    <span class="menu__toggle"></span>
   </button>
   <menu class="menu__content">
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Lorem.</li>
   </menu>
  </div>
 </header>
 <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: проверь. твой ответ не работает. необходимо, что бы при клике на document убиралась меню, а не только на кнопку.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Переделал под ваши нужды. Правильно задачи ставьте.

Comment: _...был вариант повесить обработчик на document и отслеживать target и сделать условия при попадании на кнопку меню, но так при любом клике в холостую будет работать событие._ спасибо за старания)

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный ну и будет оно срабатывать до проверки, это не ресуркоёмкие задачи, все меню делаются подобным образом +- . Вам этот вариант не подходит?

Comment: думаю подходит, но ожидал другого) если что, отмечу ваш ответ правильным с течением времени.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный сделайте отметку. Напоминание.